# The Received Actions Inspector doesn't show new connections under Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

One newbie question,

I have declared some actions for different buttons previously. But then I changed my code to call the same action method for all buttons. I delete the IBAction declaration in .h file and .m file but Interface Builder File's owner connections inspector still shows previous IBAction methods in the received actions part. I build, clean, open close project and Xcode nothing changes. So where the those actions is saved how can I delete them?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Go into IB, select the File's Owner, look at the outlets in the Inspector. Click the X button next to the action connection you want to remove.

I sometimes find I have to quit and restart Xcode to get actions to update in the inspector.